# How to make my image gallery responsive

Tags: javascript, css, html, responsive-design

I recently finished developing my interactive Video Gallery. I used HTML and CSS only. Now I'm having problems in making it responsive. As soon as I resize my browser, the images get out of frame. I want the image gallery to change no. of columns according to the browser width, without affecting the features of the gallery, or hover effects.
The link to my project folder is - 
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0Bx9r_Ov1lSfAYmxDcmJCSkY1MjA

Any help would be really appreciable.

Comment: Please provide your code, what have you tried, what kind of ideas you had...

Comment: create a plunker instead.

Comment: Didn't look at the project - could it be an option to use existing frameworks like magnific-popup and jquery? jquery helps you managing image loading and magnific-popup is an IMHO fine gallery framework.

Comment: @Armin, I have included the entire project folder, visit the google drive link I've provided.

Comment: @PranavRaghaw I saw your link, but it is not correct way of showing your code. It's better if you use plunker as Aravind suggested, or fiddle, codepen, or any similar tool. That way, it's easier for everyone to check it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use Bootstrap link in your project and you can remove inline style on your file. I have solved your error and it work perfectly ... you can try this html file in your project folder then run it ...

```html
<html>
<head>
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat" rel="stylesheet">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="thumb-css/style.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="isotope-wrap">
    <div class="col-lg-12 offset-top-34">
        <div data-isotope-layout="fitRows" data-isotope-group="gallery" class="isotope isotope--loaded" style="position: relative; height: 2100px;">
            <div class="row">
                <div data-filter="All" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-4 isotope-item">
                    <div class="inset-xl-left-20 inset-xl-right-20">
                        <a class="thumbnail-classic" href="index-variant-2.html" target="_blank">
                         <figure>
                                <img class="img-responsive" src="images/intense-570x428.jpg" alt="">
                                <figcaption class="thumbnail-classic-caption text-center">
                                    <h4 class="thumbnail-classic-title text-light" style="font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif; color: #212121;text-transform: uppercase; text-align: center; font-weight: 100">Intense</h4>
                                    <p class="thumbnail-classic-desc text-bold veil reveal-xs-block" style="font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;text-transform: uppercase;font-weight: 100;text-align: center;">Feel the power of future</p>
                                </figcaption>
                            </figure>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div data-filter="All" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-4 isotope-item" >
                    <div class="inset-xl-left-20 inset-xl-right-20">
                        <a class="thumbnail-classic" href="index-variant-2.html" target="_blank">
                            <figure>
                                <img class="img-responsive" src="images/intense-570x428.jpg" alt="">
                                <figcaption class="thumbnail-classic-caption text-center">
                                    <h4 class="thumbnail-classic-title text-light" style="font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif; color: #212121;text-transform: uppercase; text-align: center; font-weight: 100">Intense</h4>
                                    <p class="thumbnail-classic-desc text-bold veil reveal-xs-block" style="font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;text-transform: uppercase;font-weight: 100;text-align: center;">Feel the power of future</p>
                                </figcaption>
                            </figure>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div data-filter="All" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-4 isotope-item" >
                    <div class="inset-xl-left-20 inset-xl-right-20">
                        <a class="thumbnail-classic" href="index-variant-2.html" target="_blank">
                            <figure>
                                <img class="img-responsive" src="images/intense-570x428.jpg" alt="">
                                <figcaption class="thumbnail-classic-caption text-center">
                                    <h4 class="thumbnail-classic-title text-light" style="font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif; color: #212121;text-transform: uppercase; text-align: center; font-weight: 100">Intense</h4>
                                    <p class="thumbnail-classic-desc text-bold veil reveal-xs-block" style="font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;text-transform: uppercase;font-weight: 100;text-align: center;">Feel the power of future</p>
                                </figcaption>
                            </figure>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div data-filter="All" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-4 isotope-item" >
                    <div class="inset-xl-left-20 inset-xl-right-20">
                        <a class="thumbnail-classic" href="index-variant-2.html" target="_blank">
                            <figure>
                                <img class="img-responsive" src="images/intense-570x428.jpg" alt="">
                                <figcaption class="thumbnail-classic-caption text-center">
                                    <h4 class="thumbnail-classic-title text-light" style="font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif; color: #212121;text-transform: uppercase; text-align: center; font-weight: 100">Intense</h4>
                                    <p class="thumbnail-classic-desc text-bold veil reveal-xs-block" style="font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;text-transform: uppercase;font-weight: 100;text-align: center;">Feel the power of future</p>
                                </figcaption>
                            </figure>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div data-filter="All" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-4 isotope-item" >
                    <div class="inset-xl-left-20 inset-xl-right-20">
                        <a class="thumbnail-classic" href="index-variant-2.html" target="_blank">
                            <figure>
                                <img class="img-responsive" src="images/intense-570x428.jpg" alt="">
                                <figcaption class="thumbnail-classic-caption text-center">
                                    <h4 class="thumbnail-classic-title text-light" style="font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif; color: #212121;text-transform: uppercase; text-align: center; font-weight: 100">Intense</h4>
                                    <p class="thumbnail-classic-desc text-bold veil reveal-xs-block" style="font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;text-transform: uppercase;font-weight: 100;text-align: center;">Feel the power of future</p>
                                </figcaption>
                            </figure>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div data-filter="All" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-4 isotope-item" >
                    <div class="inset-xl-left-20 inset-xl-right-20">
                        <a class="thumbnail-classic" href="index-variant-2.html" target="_blank">
                            <figure>
                                <img class="img-responsive" src="images/intense-570x428.jpg" alt="">
                                <figcaption class="thumbnail-classic-caption text-center">
                                    <h4 class="thumbnail-classic-title text-light" style="font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif; color: #212121;text-transform: uppercase; text-align: center; font-weight: 100">Intense</h4>
                                    <p class="thumbnail-classic-desc text-bold veil reveal-xs-block" style="font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;text-transform: uppercase;font-weight: 100;text-align: center;">Feel the power of future</p>
                                </figcaption>
                            </figure>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot bro, it works fine. But the distance between the two texts is gone, its not like it was before.